# parsing text file in android requiring 2 keys as input

Tags: java, android, parsing

I have got a text file having following data
where first row represents pressure and first column represents temperature

user will input pressure and temperature . for e.g. : if pressure: 10 and temperature : 25 ,output should be 685.2529

txt file

```
            0.1         1           5           10          30          50          100
-150    -3411.0221  -17133.5640 -10319.7063 -3497.8667  -86.8310    -216.7636   -5992.794714
-125    -2325.2480  -11679.7207 -7034.8053  -2384.4488  -59.1915    -147.7649   -4085.207758
-100    -1528.9398  -7679.8648  -4625.6546  -1567.8667  -38.9207    -97.1611    -2686.180959
-75     -912.3368   -4582.6679  -2760.1839  -935.5649   -23.2244    -57.9772    -1602.876555
-50     -414.9822   -2084.4558  -1255.4873  -425.5477   -10.5638    -26.3713    -729.0786431
-25     0.0000      0.0000      0.0000      0.0000      0.0000      0.0000      0
0       355.9246    1787.8091   1076.8142   364.9864    9.0604      22.6183     625.3207382
25      668.2396    3356.5673   2021.6920   685.2529    17.0107     42.4653     1174.024214
50      947.2608    4758.0910   2865.8428   971.3781    24.1135     60.1965     1664.234178
75      1200.8310   6031.7742   3632.9942   1231.4042   30.5684     76.3104     2109.729457
100     1434.4221   7205.1022   4339.7006   1470.9425   36.5146     91.1547     2520.123568
125     5.0236      25.2337     15.1985     5.1515      0.1279      0.3192      8.825988908
```

How to parse it when there are 2 keys as inputs i.e. pressure and temperature
I am using android studio 3.6 and java as programming language

reading text file from Assets folder with following code

```
 try {
                        reader = new BufferedReader(
                                new InputStreamReader(getAssets().open("compressibility.txt"), "UTF-8"));

                        // do reading, usually loop until end of file reading
                        String mLine;

                        while ((mLine = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                           // tv.setText(mLine);
                           **// parse and process data**

                        }
                      //  tv.setText(file_full);
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        //log the exception
                    } finally {
                        if (reader != null) {
                            try {
                                reader.close();
                            } catch (IOException e) {
                                //log the exception
                            }
                        }
                    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given below is how you can do it in Java for console input:

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Paths;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String[] pressure = null;
        String[] temperature = null;
        String[][] data = null;
        int lineCount, index = 0;
        String[] tokens;
        Scanner file = null;
        String line;
        try {
            // Count the no. of lines in the files
            lineCount = (int) Files.lines(Paths.get("file.txt")).count();

            // The size temperature[] = no. of lines - 1 because 1st line is for pressure
            // data
            temperature = new String[lineCount - 1];

            file = new Scanner(new File("file.txt"));
            if (file.hasNextLine()) {
                // Read the first line (pressure data)
                pressure = file.nextLine().split("\\s+");// Split the line on space(s)
            }

            // The no. of rows in data[][] = no. of lines - 1 because 1st line is for
            // pressure data
            data = new String[lineCount - 1][pressure.length];

            // Drop pressure[0] from pressure[] as there is no data there
            pressure = Arrays.copyOfRange(pressure, 1, pressure.length);

            // Read lines until the file is exhausted
            while (file.hasNextLine()) {
                line = file.nextLine();
                tokens = line.split("\\s+");
                temperature[index] = tokens[0];// The first data in the line is temperature

                // Drop tokens[0] from token[] as it has already been stored into temperature[]
                // and store the remaining part of token[] into data[index]
                data[index] = Arrays.copyOfRange(tokens, 1, tokens.length);
                index++;
            }
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            System.out.println("Unable to read data.");
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println("Unable to read data.");
        }
        file.close();// Close the scanner for file
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);// Create a scanner for input from console
        System.out.print("Enter the value of pressure: ");
        String p = in.nextLine();
        System.out.print("Enter the value of temperature: ");
        String t = in.nextLine();
        int pIndex = indexOf(p, pressure);// Search for p in pressure[]
        int tIndex = indexOf(t, temperature);// Search for t in temperature[]
        if (pIndex != -1 && tIndex != -1) {
            System.out.println("The required data is: " + data[tIndex][pIndex]);
        } else {
            System.out.println("Data not found.");
        }
    }

    static int indexOf(String value, String[] array) {
        for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
            if (value.equals(array[i])) {
                return i;// Return index if value is found in array
            }
        }
        return -1;// Return -1 if value is not found in array
    }
}
```

**Note:** Content of `file.txt` is exactly what you have posted in the question.

**A sample run:**

```
Enter the value of pressure: 10
Enter the value of temperature: 25
The required data is: 685.2529
```

Feel free to comment in case of any doubt/issue.

Comment: is it ok to put linecount =13 ?

Comment: Of course, you can do that if you already know that there are 13 lines.

Comment: Its very helpful ,  System.out.println("The required data is: " + data[tIndex][pIndex - 1]);   ? this is correct ?

Comment: As per the code, the correct code would be `System.out.println("The required data is: " + data[tIndex][pIndex]);`. There is no problem with `System.out.println("The required data is: " + data[tIndex][pIndex-1]);` syntactically, but it may give you incorrect result. Is there any reason to do so?

Comment: pressure = Arrays.copyOfRange(pressure, 1, pressure.length - 1); pressure.length coming out to be 6 whereas it should be 7

Comment: @G.ONE - Fixed it. Test again and feel free to comment in case of any further issue/doubt.

Comment: Perfect! I wish you success!